# Don't suggest 'var' type for basic types like String, arrays, primitives and boxed primitives

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How can I stop IntelliJ from warning about explicit types like `String`, arrays, primitives and boxed primitives and suggesting to convert them into `var`?

Currently I have this:

[image: IntelliJ screenshot]

IntelliJ is displaying the type of the local variable `foo` as gray, suggesting to convert it to `var`. This is intended behavior for me. However, in the following lines IntelliJ suggests converting primitives, boxed primitives, arrays and `String` into `var`. I don't want those to be marked as warnings. I believe the `var` feature is a great addition to Java, however in my opinion some types should remain explicit to improve readability.

Additionally, when I create a local variable to store the return value from `foo2.getValue()`, IntelliJ suggests the type of the variable to be `var`. I also don't want this, it should be the explicit type `Double`.

I only found this inspection, allowing me to turn off the suggestions to convert variables to `var`, but I only want to disable it for specific types. Usually inspections allow to disable them under specific conditions, this one does not.

[image: inspection]

Is it possible to configure IntelliJ to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no option to configure the inspection to trigger only on particular types. Please follow/add the related feature request on your issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217466 or create a new one at YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com).